# c++ How to inline private class fields?

Tags: c++, performance, oop, c++14, c++17

currently i'm writing a library for a micro-controller. Most micro-controller have more flash memory then RAM. My question is not hardware or micro-controller related, it is just important that I can reduce the ram usage. I will explain my problem with an example.

---

**MyClass.h**

```
class myClass
{
    public:
        myClass(int _pinA, int _pinB)
        : pinA{_pinA}, pinB{_pinB} {};
        void doSomething(); //for example turnOn(pinB);
    private:
        const int pinA, pinB;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    myClass object(2,3);
    object.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

So if the compiler see turnOn(pinB), it must replace pinB with the value of pinB (preprocessing). You can achieve that if you use define, but in my case i can't use it.

---

The pin variables are stored in ram as long as the object is alive. Is it possible to make the compiler paste the value of pinA or pinB every occur? In that way, the vars are stored in flash (program) memory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sue I understand your question. Constants to get "pasted" into the code. But when running it has to be loaded into RAM (or CPU register), otherwise the CPU has no access to it.

Comment: use a static object? create a template? note: these type of questions usually come up becase OPs try to be too "clever" and create an artificial problem. don't add needless complexity.

Comment: You could make `myClass` a template that takes two integer parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Even if they were non-member variables, just giving them a `const` declaration does not require the compiler to not give them storage. That's ultimately up to the compiler to deal with. Even `constexpr` variables can be given storage by the compiler.

The fact that they are *member* variables makes it pretty much impossible for the compiler to just throw them away and still be able to follow the C++ memory model. Oh sure, it is *possible* for a compiler to be able to do so in certain circumstances. But there is nothing you can do to *guarantee* it.

You can however encourage the compiler to eliminate the storage. One way to do that is to make `myClass` a literal type and declare the variable containing that object as `constexpr`. This would guarantee nothing; getting a reference or pointer to the object or any of its subobjects could easily cause the compiler to have to give it memory. But it would make it easier for the compiler to remove the object when it is not strictly necessary.